# Adding what's inside a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a function that will make a list of all the cubes less than n. Then all those numbers together and print that out however the .count() doesn't work as I was hoping. Is there a way to count up every number of the list or do I have to go through the list one by one to add them up?

```
def sum_cubes_less(n):
    '''Return the sum of the cubes of the positive integers less than n.'''
    x = 1
    cubes = [x**3 for x in range(1,n)]
    return cubes.count()

 print(sum_cubes_less(2**8))
```

Comment: `sum()` is probably what you're looking for

Comment: `sum([1,2,3])` gives you 6. Check out [official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is for counting the number of occurrences that appears in the list.

You want to use `sum` for suming all your cubes.
Also you can avoid saving all your cubes in a list in memory (since you only want the total sum) by computing the cube then adding to the sum.

```
def sum_cubes_less(n):
   '''Return the sum of the cubes of the positive integers less than n.'''
    return sum(x**3 for x in range(1, n))
```

Edit: using the generator form is simplier, less heavy and faster.

Comment: thanks you. I wasn't sure if I could do all of it in one line, since I had the wrong method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sum all the cubes, the sum of the first n cubes can be calculated with `((n( n + 1) / 2)^2)`:

```
In [6]: n = 25

In [7]: sum(x ** 3 for x in range(1, n+1))
Out[7]: 105625

In [8]: (n * ( n + 1) / 2) ** 2
Out[8]: 105625
```

If you are using range you need to use `n+1` to include n in the result.

To not include n just subtract 1 from n:

```
In [16]: n = 25

In [17]: sum(x ** 3 for x in range(1, n))
Out[17]: 90000

In [18]: n -= 1

In [19]: (n * ( n + 1) // 2) ** 2
Out[19]: 90000
```

Comment: right I guess I forgot to mention I don not need the nth term

Comment: Nice one. This should be accepted as the best answer this it does not use loops and is surely way faster. Also for a short explanation  1^3 + 2^3 +...+ n^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2 = (n*(n+1)/2)^2

Answer (score 1):

change

```
return cubes.count()
```

to

```
return sum(cubes)
```

Check out [official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `sum()`

replace `return cubes.count()`
with `return sum(cubes)`

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) for this task.

```
return sum(cubes)
```

This will return `1065369600` for your input value of `2**8`.

---

[`.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns the number of times a specific item is in a list. You have to pass it a value to check:

```
return cubes.count(27)
```

This returns `1` because 3*3*3 is 27 and that value appears 1 time.